# Set printing area In Excel 2013 using macro

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2013, having sheet named *"Tags"*, I am trying to **set a printing area** from `A2` till end of page, ending with column `L`.

```
Worksheets("Tags").PageSetup.PrintArea = Worksheets("Tags").Range( _
  Cells(2, 1), Cells(Worksheets("Tags").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row, 12))
```

My code compiles okay, but it does not seems to work - no printing area has been set.

What should be a correct macro to set printing area?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's easier to see what is happening if you declare a few variables and decompose your statement.

Try this:

```
Sub SetPrintArea()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim lastRow As Long

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tags")

  ' find the last row with formatting, to be included in print range
  lastRow = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

  ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ws.Range("A2:L" & lastRow).Address
End Sub
```

Alternatively, if you want to find the lastRow with data, you can find the lastrow like this:

```
lastRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Note that the 65536 value you're using as the starting point to find the last row is obsolete (although it will frequently still work) as of Excel 2007, which has over a million rows per sheet.

A few things to note about your approach:

1. `Cells(2,1)` is A2. The syntax is `Cells([row], [column])`
2. You want the last populated row in column L, but are looking in column A instead. `Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`

This results in a print area (once you've added the .Address to your range) of A1:L2. Why A1? Because the column A is empty, and the lastrow is therefore row 1. You have set the range to be A2:L1, which becomes A1:L2.

Comment: I've added an explanation in my answer explaining why the range you've specified results in a printarea of A1:L2.

Comment: To clarify my question - I want selection till last row, regardless of column, so even if `L` is empty/blank.

Comment: Gotcha. I've edited my answer so that it correctly finds the last row regardless of column.

Comment: Did my explanation of why your range ended up being A1:L2 make sense?

Comment: I will stick with `Worksheets("Tags").PageSetup.PrintArea = Worksheets("Tags").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Worksheets("Tags").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 12)).Address`, because your code is looking for the bottom based on values, so when I have some additional formatting (such as lines/borders), it is cut and not printed...

Comment: I edited my answer to find the last row in the usedrange. Note that if the usedrange doesn't start in the first row, you'll want to set the lastrow by adding the blank rows at the top of the sheet to the `usedrange.rows.count`.

Comment: @HeadofCatering I'm glad you mentioned this, a lot of people aren't aware. I suppose `Range("A1", Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))` is an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `.Address` at the end of your code.

```
    Worksheets("Tags").PageSetup.PrintArea = Worksheets("Tags").Range( _
        Cells(2, 1), Cells(Worksheets("Tags").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row, 12)).Address
```

**PageSetup.PrintArea Property**

> Returns or sets the range to be printed, as a string using A1-style references in the language of the macro. Read/write String.

Comment: Regardless of content, it returns `$A$1:$L$2`. Why `$A$1` and why `$L$2`..?

Comment: That's part of it, but OP also has the wrong range specified. He wants B2 to be the start of the printarea, but specifies `Cells(2,1)`, which is A2.

Comment: This one works: `Worksheets("Tags").PageSetup.PrintArea = Worksheets("Tags").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Worksheets("Tags").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 12)).Address`

Comment: Thanks @HeadofCatering I didn't pick-up on the (2,1). I assumed also that the OP was using column A because it was populated.

Comment: And it turns out A2 was the correct starting point after all. B2 was a typo. :-)