# Pivot Slicer Items to PDF - via file dialog folder picker

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all and thank you for taking the time to read.

In relation to the code below (code provided by M--) from this post [VBA to select each slicer item AND then save each selected slicer item as a pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481343/vba-to-select-each-slicer-item-and-then-save-each-selected-slicer-item-as-a-pdf)

Rather than a predetermined save / export location i would like the user to select a folder of their choice.

I have been politely informed in stack chat by @QHarr that i need a filedialog object to introduce this function. Would this be at the beginning of the module? Is export better than save.as in this scenario? Would the latter effect the way the slicer items are transferred?

Much appreciated and kind regards

wAnd

```
Public Sub myMacro()
Dim sC As SlicerCache
Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Store_Number")

'This reminds the user to only select the first slicer item
   If sC.VisibleSlicerItems.Count <> 1 Or sC.SlicerItems(1).Selected = False Then
      MsgBox "Please Only Select Store-Number 1"
      Exit Sub
   End If


For i = 1 To sC.SlicerItems.Count

    'Do not clear ilter as it causes to select all of the items (sC.ClearManualFilter)

    sC.SlicerItems(i).Selected = True
    If i <> 1 Then sC.SlicerItems(i - 1).Selected = False


    'Debug.Print sI.Name
    'add export to PDF code here
    With Sheet18.PageSetup

    .PrintArea = Sheet18.Range("A1:N34" & lastRow).Address

    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1

    End With

    Sheet18.Range("M1") = sC.SlicerItems(i).Name

   'This prints to C directory, change the path as you wish

   Sheet18.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\" & Range("M1").Text & ".pdf", Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking around i have managed to solve it. In a nutshell i didnt use the back slash for Filename:=path & \ & Range("G2").Text

Final code below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 

Dim sC As SlicerCache 

Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Site_Product") 

Dim dialog As FileDialog 

Dim path As String 

  

    Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 

    dialog.AllowMultiSelect = False 

    If dialog.Show = -1 Then 

    path = dialog.SelectedItems(1) 

  

'This reminds the user to only select the first slicer item 

   If sC.VisibleSlicerItems.Count <> 1 Or sC.SlicerItems(1).Selected = False Then 

      MsgBox "Please select the top most item" 

      Exit Sub 

   End If 

  

  

For i = 1 To sC.SlicerItems.Count 

  

    'Do not clear ilter as it causes to select all of the items (sC.ClearManualFilter) 

  

    sC.SlicerItems(i).Selected = True 

    If i <> 1 Then sC.SlicerItems(i - 1).Selected = False 

  

  

    'Debug.Print sI.Name 

    'add export to PDF code here 

    With Sheet5.PageSetup 

  

    .PrintArea = Sheet5.Range("B2:M76" & lastRow).Address 

  

    .FitToPagesWide = 1 

    .FitToPagesTall = 1 

  

    End With 

  

    Sheet5.Range("G2") = sC.SlicerItems(i).Name 

     

    For Each CL In Sheet5.Range("M11:M67") 

    If CL.WrapText Then CL.Rows.AutoFit 

    Sheet5.Range("A1:A74").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sheet5.Range("A2") 

    Next 

  

   'This prints to C directory, change the path as you wish 

  

   Sheet5.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=path & "\" & Range("G2").Text, Quality:= _ 

    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _ 

    OpenAfterPublish:=False 

Next 

End If 

End Sub
```